# Iterate through cells in a range

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, I'm using the following code to check column A in a certain range of cells for a #N/A value, and if found, I'm deleting that row.

```
With Sheets(Sheet)
        For LRow = 45 To 29 Step -1
            With .Cells(LRow, "A")
                If (CVErr(.Value) = CVErr(xlErrNA)) Then .EntireRow.Delete
            End With
        Next LRow
    End With
```

I need to extend this so I check all columns 1 through 10, rather than just A. I tried this slight modification (nesting another loop), but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
With Sheets(Sheet)
        For LRow = 45 To 29 Step -1
            For LCol = 10 To 1 Step -1
                With .Cells(LRow, LCol)
                    If (CVErr(.Value) = CVErr(xlErrNA)) Then .EntireRow.Delete
                End With
            Next LCol
        Next LRow
    End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two issues here:

- the nested with
- on on any given row once N/A is found, you need yo abort the loop

try

```
Set sh = Sheets(Sheet)
For LRow = 45 To 29 Step -1
    For LCol = 10 To 1 Step -1
        If (CVErr(sh.Cells(LRow, LCol).Value) = CVErr(xlErrNA)) Then 
            sh.Cells(LRow, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            Exit For ' Exit the LCol loop
        End If
    Next LCol
Next LRow
```

Answer (score 2):

This might fail in languages other than English

```
Sub DeleteNA()

    Dim rRange As Range
    Dim rFound As Range

    Const sNA As String = "#N/A"

    Do
        Set rRange = Sheet1.Range("A29:F49")
        Set rFound = rRange.Find(sNA, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            rFound.EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Change the A29:F49 to suit your data.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a slightly different approach

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Set cols = Range("A1:D80")
For Each Cell In cols
    If Cell.Value = "XXX" Then
        Cell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I get a 'Object doesn't support property or method at the Set Selection line

Comment: You need to select the sheet first - I have added that in

Comment: Okay, "selection" was a bad choice of variable name. Edited answer accordingly. VBA automatically changed "selection" to "Selection" which is a reserved keyword...

Answer (score 0):

I believe there were problems in the nested 'with' clauses you used.

You could define a proper range and use a 'for each' loop, that would make things clearer and easier to read. I named a range as 'MyRange' for testing purposes.

```
Sub test()

    Dim cell As Excel.Range

    For Each cell In [myRange]

        If CVErr(cell.Value) = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then cell.EntireRow.Delete

    Next cell

End Sub
```